# R: Given the column location info, replace data elements in different columns

Tags: r

I have two data with 3 columns and 4 rows. What I need to do is to replace some elements in df1 with values in df2 at the same place. If the elements that need to be replaced are in the same column, this job will be done easily. But, my problem is that they are in different columns. I have a matrix (here, `info`) with the information that what column should be replaced. Below is an example. The `info` indicates that for the first three rows, the 1st and 3rd columns need to be changed, and for the last row, the 2nd and 3rd columns need to be changed.

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <-matrix(sample(1:1000, 12, replace=T), ncol=3)
df2 <-round(matrix(runif(12, 0.1, 0.9),ncol=3),1)
info<-matrix(rep(1:3, 4),ncol=3, byrow=T)
info<-t(apply(info, 1, function(x) sort(sample(x, 2, replace=F))))

> df1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  266  202  630
[2,]  373  899   62
[3,]  573  945  206
[4,]  909  661  177
> df2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.6  0.7  0.8
[2,]  0.4  0.9  0.3
[3,]  0.7  0.4  0.6
[4,]  0.5  0.7  0.2
> info
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    2    3
```

From this example, I want to get results that look like,

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.6  202  0.8
[2,]  0.4  899  0.3
[3,]  0.7  945  0.6
[4,]  909  0.7  0.2
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to construct `info` to contain the matrix-entries which are to be updated. The below converts your `info` matrix to a proper index matrix.

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <-matrix(sample(1:1000, 12, replace=T), ncol=3)
df2 <-round(matrix(runif(12, 0.1, 0.9),ncol=3),1)
info<-matrix(rep(1:3, 4),ncol=3, byrow=T)
info<-t(apply(info, 1, function(x) sort(sample(x, 2, replace=F))))

# Convert info to a index matrix
info_new <- cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(info)), ncol(info)), c(info))
print(info_new)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    1   <- row 2, col 1
#[3,]    3    1
#[4,]    4    2
#[5,]    1    3
#[6,]    2    3
#[7,]    3    3   <- row 3, col 3
#[8,]    4    3    etc

df1[info_new] <- df2[info_new] 
print(df1)
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   0.6 202.0  0.8
#[2,]   0.4 899.0  0.3
#[3,]   0.7 945.0  0.6
#[4,] 909.0   0.7  0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop over rows of `df1`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) df1[i,info[i,]]<-df2[i,info[i,]]
df1
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,]   0.6 202.0  0.8
[2,]   0.4 899.0  0.3
[3,]   0.7 945.0  0.6
[4,] 909.0   0.7  0.2
```